# What SSIS "error code 0xC0202092" means? (DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED)

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, import-from-csv

Here it is below a full dump of the SSIS complains. Please note that I imported the same data in the destination table by using a different tool already and everything is looking perfectly, I suppose that means the schema of the destination table is correct.  What do I have to do here to actually use SSIS (the entire process is automated, I did it manually now but that is not acceptable in long term...)

[Flat File Source [170]] Error: Data conversion failed. 
The data conversion for column "City" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[Flat File Source [170]] Error: The "output column "City" (203)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "City" (203)" 
specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

[Flat File Source [170]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "G:\Share\Nationwide Charities Listing.csv" on data row 120.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (170) returned error code 0xC0202092.
The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). 
The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Maybe you should investigate whats on/around data row 120 ? and whats so different in the City value for that row? 

To investigate further, it would be good if you could post the destination schema and a sample data row. Would be helpful for anyone here willing to shed some light to this matter. Cheers.

Comment: The "offending" city is "Montréal", the field type is varchar(23).
Please note that the other tool (EMS Data import for SQL Server) imported it perfectly. Please also note that line 120 isn't the first occurence  of the "offending" city, but I suppose order doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 2):

Your data contains unicode characters i guess and the destination is varchar(23). Try to change it to nvarchar(23) and then import ?

Answer (score 1):

Use utf 8 and you will be fine. That is in the first screen after the welcome in the import export tool. That displays properly the accents.